# racket error: possibly, bytecode file needs re-compile because

Tags: emacs, racket

Occasionally, I get the following error while loading a racket file (.rkt) using the Emacs racket-mode (using `C-c C-z`). This is with racket 8.6, Emacs 28 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

```
reference to a variable that is not exported;
 possibly, bytecode file needs re-compile because dependencies changed
  name: handle-pre-post/desc-string
  exporting instance: "/usr/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/arrow-higher-order.rkt"
  importing instance: "/usr/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/arrow-val-first.rkt"
```

It seems that the error happens only when I load the source file both in Emacs and in the Dr Racket IDE. If I close everything and open the file with Emacs only, the error does not seem to happen. Also, the error only happens on the Emacs side. Dr Racket IDE never had an issue opening and running the same file.

My questions are:

What does the `bytecode file needs re-compile` message mean? Is it because I edited the code in two editors (Emacs and Dr Racket) simultaneously?

What is the correct way to re-complile bytecode files to avoid the error, other than maybe closing all files?

Comment: Iirc, DrRacket doesn't use precompiled files as its default; racket-mode might. So if you edit and save a file in DrRacket it becomes out of sync with the compiled version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seeing this while editing files in both DrRacket and then running the code from the terminal; but I'm new to racket so no idea what to do next - I haven't seen this in the few weeks previous I've been hacking on this.

[Update]

I removed the contents of `<srcdir>/compiled/` and the command ran from the terminal, might be worth trying.